# Issue while declaring in header file

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10

I am trying to declare navigation pane in the header file, as suggested in the link([Image Link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development/Doubts-regarding-the-creating-stack-of-screen-and-its-navigation/td-p/1805445)),

Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue.I want all the things to be written on C++, rather than QML. Any assistance from you guys will be useful

Regards

Rakesh Shankar.P

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say, why your code is not working. Maybe this is related to other errors that occur. What you could try is not to include those header files for the NavigationPane and the Page but to forward declare them, which will work since you are only declare variables as pointers to those classes. So remove those includes and instead write

```
#include <...>

class NavigationPane;
class Page;

class App : ....
```

As a common rule: If possible, you should include as less as possible in the header. As long as you don't need the type information in the class declaration (which is given, when using pointers to objects), you can move the includes to the cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

Classes `NavigationPane` and `Page` are inside `bb::cascades` namespace. You have to declare them as:

```
bb::cascades::NavigationPane * mRoot;
bb::cascades::Page * mNewPage.
```

or put `using namespace bb::cascades;` before that (but it is a terrible practice to do so in a header file, so don't).